# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException after adding bean.jar to WEB-INF/lib

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am studying MVC ,created a demo dynamic web project and not using  maven yet.

I have add necessay jars in in build path, but when I run , it says the Dispatcher class can not be found ...

also I am not quite clear about how WebApplicationContext works in Spring-MVC , since in a "normal spring project" we create the ApplicationCotext by new `ClassPath...()` constructor. But how and when the `WebApplicationConText` be instanciated, really no idea.

So I Tried to add the jars in the `WEB-INF/lib`, at the begning , it seemed to be the solution . but when I add the spring-beans 4.3.0 Tomcat will always throw a `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8007]]`

can anyone help on this and recommend me some materials for Tomcat ? I want to look inside it

[image: Here's my project snipping]

Comment: a view of your build libraries should be helpful !!

Comment: failed to put the snipping last nit for poor connection , now added, tks for ur reminder

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are mission some jar to be added
please make sure that you have below jars added...
According to spring-webmvc 3.1.2 need following jar:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Also, i am confused about the jars path. I tried , it doesn't work when put jars in elcipse project build-path, but fine in my project-WEB-INF/lib , any comments on this ? tks